# How to resize WPF user control inside the DevExpress LayoutPanel

Tags: wpf, user-controls, devexpress

How to resize the user control automatically to stretch fit inside the DevExpress Dock LayoutPanel? I have tried below approach but it does not work. When I resize the layout panel by mouse, then the user control inside the panel is expected to stretch accordingly to fit the panel.

In my parent control XAML....\

```
<dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
<dxdo:LayoutGroup x:Name="RootGroup" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
       <dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="FundMapPanel" Caption="Fund Map" ItemWidth="400" ItemHeight="320">
            <cont:FundMapUserControl></cont:FundMapUserControl>
       </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
</dxdo:LayoutGroup>
</dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
```

And in my user control XAML..

```
<UserControl
. . .
. . .
Width="{Binding ElementName=FundMapPanel, Path=ItemWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"
Height="{Binding ElementName=FundMapPanel, Path=ItemHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"

. . .
. . .
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `RelativeResouce` and `ParentType`? Or perhaps just removing `Width`  and `Height` and setting `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAligment` to `Stretched` instead ?

Comment: Yes that is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct approach:

```
<dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
    <dxdo:LayoutGroup x:Name="RootGroup">
       <dxdo:LayoutPanel x:Name="FundMapPanel" Caption="Fund Map" ItemWidth="400" ItemHeight="320">
            <cont:FundMapUserControl 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalAligment ="Stretch"
            />
       </dxdo:LayoutPanel>
    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
</dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
```

As you can see there are no bindings to [ItemHeight](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.BaseLayoutItem.ItemHeight.property)/[ItemWidth](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.BaseLayoutItem.ItemWidth.property) at all - inner control **is stretched** to fill the entire content of the LayoutPanel.
Note that you can't use the [ItemHeight](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.BaseLayoutItem.ItemHeight.property)/[ItemWidth](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Docking.BaseLayoutItem.ItemWidth.property) properties because they are System.Windows.GridLength objects.